# Clicking a button should get an Ajax response, but reloads the whole page in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, phantomjs, submit, casperjs

I'm playing around with CasperJS and trying to catch some Free-Email Alias on https://registrierung.web.de/#.homepage.loginbox_1.1.registrierung

So I have the input field: "E-Mail-Wunschname:" where I want to paste a name, then click the "Prüfen" button and then just scrape the suggested accounts.

So far I have tried that:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: true,
        userAgent:('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0')
    }

});

var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);

casper.start('https://registrierung.web.de/#.homepage.loginbox_1.1.registrierung').viewport(1200,1000);

casper.then(
    function() {               
        this.sendKeys('.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField',"Test");
        this.sendKeys('.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField',casper.page.event.key.Enter);       
        this.wait(5000);        
    }
);
casper.then(function() {
    this.wait(5000);
    this.capture('webde.png');
    console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});


casper.run();
```

I also tired to click the button with:

```
casper.wait(6000, function() {
    this.evaluate(function(){                 
        document.querySelector('.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField').value = "Test";           
        document.querySelector('#checkAvailabilityBtn').click();
            });
    });
    casper.then(function() {
        this.capture('webde.png');
        console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
    });
```

With both ways it's just a complete submit of the page and not just the generation of the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the button (`casper.click("#checkAvailabilityBtn")`) seems to work well.

Here is the full script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('https://registrierung.web.de/#.homepage.loginbox_1.1.registrierung').viewport(1200,1000);

casper.then(function() {               
    this.sendKeys('.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField', "Test"); 
    this.click("#checkAvailabilityBtn");
});
casper.wait(5000);
casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('test80_webde.png');
    console.log('clicked ok, new location is ' + this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

By the way, `casper.sendKeys()` is not able to handle key presses such as the Enter key. You would need to use PhantomJS' `page.sendEvent()` function. It works normally in the following way, but doesn't seem to work correctly in this case, because it reloads the page:

```
this.sendKeys('.wishname.feedback-panel-trigger.multiReplaceCharsInWishnamelField', "Test", {keepFocus: true}); 
this.page.sendEvent("keypress", this.page.event.key.Enter);
```

Comment: hmm, thanks, but its not work well. The Click submits the whole page. try it in a "normal" browser and you see what i mean.

Comment: shame on me! The "Test" in SendKeys was the Problem. I tried it with "Chrisko" than it works...